# when trying to save a new contribution the civi logo just spins and spins

Tags: civicontribute, error

this is the error
TypeError: Return value of CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::getDefaultPriceFieldID() must be of the type int, null returned in CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->getDefaultPriceFieldID() (line 671 of /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php
any idea how to fix would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Drupal 7 civicrm 5.47.3 if that matters

Answer (score 2):

This is because your system has a line item with a missing price field or price field value.

Run the below query to find if there are line items with a missing price field or price field value.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM civicrm_line_item
WHERE price_field_id IS NULL OR price_field_value_id IS NULL;
```

If the count is more than 0 after running above query then run the below query

```
SELECT @price_field_id := cpf.id, @price_field_value_id := cpfv.id
FROM civicrm_price_field_value cpfv
  INNER JOIN civicrm_price_field cpf
    ON cpf.id = cpfv.price_field_id
  INNER JOIN civicrm_price_set cps
    ON cps.id = cpf.price_set_id
      AND cps.name = 'default_contribution_amount';

 UPDATE civicrm_line_item 
 SET price_field_id = @price_field_id
 WHERE price_field_id IS NULL;

 UPDATE civicrm_line_item 
 SET price_field_value_id = @price_field_value_id
 WHERE price_field_value_id IS NULL;
```