# Network Error - TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setPriceSetID() must be of the type integer, null given

Tags: civicontribute

we're on Drupal 7.x and CiviCRM 5.52.2. We recently did a rather large upgrade and also upgraded to the iATS 1.7.4 CiviCRM Extension.

On certain contribution tabs on contact records, we're getting a "Network Error". Upon further investigation we're seeing the PHP error in Drupal log:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setPriceSetID() must be of the type integer, null given, called in sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 910 in CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->setPriceSetID() (line 471 of /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php)
```

Any clue what might be missing/incorrect in the records in the table? Appreciate the help. Can post more info if needed.

Edit, looks like this might be a duplicate of https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3150

Edit2: Looks like this patch resolved my issue https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23087.patch

from here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this patch resolved my issue https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23087.patch

from here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23087

Comment: Note that in the comments and the lab ticket that patch isn't really the right solution because there are going to be other places that also expect a price field to be present - you need to update the line items in your database to have a price field - which field depends on what the financial type is. There is no perfect recipe, but the lab ticket gives some ideas.

Comment: @Demerit do you expect that a solution will be offered that does not need a database update? I was using webform_civicrm on D7 and I believe it caused my issue

Comment: webform d7 had an update for it: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/621, just I'm not sure it's a complete fix. Events have no default price set and if you have two line items on a contribution that end up with the same price field civi doesn't like that. But that patch should help.

Comment: But to fix the existing records, you need to update them in the db.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I'll make sure to do so.

Comment: @Demerit speaking of the above, do you have a suggestion for how to fix the missing price field association? In our case, we used webform and created memberships/contributions and some event registrations.

Comment: You can use this to get the default ids: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3150#note_70991. And this might help: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41629/when-trying-to-save-a-new-contribution-the-civi-logo-just-spins-and-spins/41630#41630