# Network Error while trying to view a contribution payment

Tags: civicontribute

While trying to view payment information for a contribution I get an error message popup window that says "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again".

The url for the view payment link I am trying to access is:
https://ourdomain.com/civicrm/payment?view=transaction&component=contribution&action=browse&cid=2832&id=3225&selector=1&snippet=json

If I try to go to this url directly, I get the error message:

"One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer"

I tried to replicate the call using API Explorer v4 but was unable to find a browse action for the entity "Contribution".

I am still somewhat new to CiviCRM and am not sure where to go next with regards to troubleshooting this issue.

Detailed error info from ConfigAndLog:

```
Sep 01 17:38:05  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#2835
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Type.php"
    #line: 469
    trace: {
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Type.php:469 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1737 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1619 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/BAO/FinancialTrxn.php:35 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php:3609 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contribute/Form/AbstractEditPayment.php:755 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contribute/Form/AdditionalPayment.php:78 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Form.php:668 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:292 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php:88 {
        Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke($args)
        › ob_start();
        › $content = \CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke($args);
        › $output = ob_get_clean();
        arguments: {
          $args: array:2 [ …2]
        }
      }
      /var/www/libertarian/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php:80 { …}
      Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main() {}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:123 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php:573 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:124 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:97 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:151 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php:57 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php:47 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:106 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:85 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php:47 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php:52 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:708 { …}
      /var/www/libertarian/web/index.php:19 { …}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Look in ConfigAndLog for the full error: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories

Comment: May be similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41629/when-trying-to-save-a-new-contribution-the-civi-logo-just-spins-and-spins/41630#41630 ?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the detailed error info from ConfigAndLog

Comment: Hi I see you've made an edit to the answer which is really a comment. Can you convert that edit into a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the stack trace it sounds like maybe the "Accounts Receivable Account" has been deleted. Look under Admin - CiviContribute - Financial Accounts. You're not supposed to be able to delete it but stranger things have happened.

OP: I checked this and saw that there were no financial accounts assigned to the financial type we were using in the affected records. I assigned some financial accounts and can now view, edit and delete those records. Thanks!